# D3.js: Adding class whose name is based on data

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

D3 has 2 ways of setting a class:

```
selection.attr("class", (d) => d.isFoo ? "foo" : "");
selection.classed("foo", (d) => d.isFoo)
```

I'm looking for a way to add a class named as per the data. I.e. something like:

```
selection.classed((d) => "node" + d.id, true);
```

- I don't want to use `id` because multiple DOM elements will share that class.
- I don't want to use `attr` because it may potentially overwrite other classes already there.

So I could do

```
selection.attr("class", (d) => d3.select(this).attr("class") + " node" + d.id);
```

which feels a bit hackish.

Any better solution? Or a feature underway?

Comment: `selection.attr("class", (d) => d3.select(this).attr("class") + " node" + d.id);` is exactly the same as `selection.classed((d) => "node" + d.id, true);`

Comment: @Dummy No, it's not the same. If you do this `selection.classed((d) => "node" + d.id, true);`, it will give **all** your elements this strange class: `".(d) => "node" + d.name"`. Strange and not valid, by the way. The whole function will be treated as a string. Try it and you'll see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although Gerardo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41970703/4235784) is correct and comes with a proper explanation, I think, the easiest way to mess with an element's classes is to resort to its [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property which it inherits from the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) interface.

> The **`Element.classList`** is a read-only property which returns a live [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) collection of the class attributes of the element.

Although the property itself is read-only, it provides [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) for adding, removing and toggling classes. Calling `.add()` will automatically take care of classes previously set and check if the class to add has already been assigned to the element:

> **add( String [, String] )**
>
> Add specified class values. If these classes already exist in attribute of the element, then they are ignored.

Adding a class based on data can thus be done using `selection.each()`:

```
divs.each(function(d) {
  this.classList.add("node" + d.name);
});
```

Within the `.each()` method `this` points to the actual element and can be used to directly access the `classList` property.

```js
var data = [{name: "foo"}, 
            {name: "bar"},
            {name: "baz"}];

var body = d3.select("body");

var divs = body.selectAll("myDivs")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
      .attr("class", "someClass");

divs.each(function(d) {
  this.classList.add("node" + d.name);
});

//log the classes, you can see the previous class ("someClass") was not overwritten:
divs.each(function() {
    console.log(d3.select(this).attr("class"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great find, thanks! Although, it's also a very new feature: http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

Comment: Well, it's not *that* new... At the time of writing most browsers support the property. It has been in FF and Chrome for some 4 years! IE 10 and 11, on the other hand, still *"Does not have support for classList on SVG or MathML elements."*. Since you are dealing with divs and nearly all other browsers seem to be fine with it I'd give it a try.

Comment: Okay, tried, works, probably supported enough to rely on it. I'm changing accepted answer to this.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass a function to `classed()` the way you want (i.e., as the first argument). The [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_classed) is clear about `classed()`:

> *selection*.classed(names[, value])
>
> If a value is specified, assigns or unassigns the specified CSS class names on the selected elements by setting the class attribute or modifying the classList property and returns this selection. The specified names is a **string** of space-separated class names. (emphasis mine)

Thus, you **cannot** pass a function to the class name. The class name there has to be **fixed**.

That being said, what you're doing right now to **add** a class name without overwriting a previously existing class...

```
selection.attr("class", (d) => d3.select(this).attr("class") + " node" + d.id);
```

... seems to be the standard way among D3 coders, even if you feel that it's a hack. However, you need a small modification here: don't use `this` with an arrow function, it's not going to work (check this example [d3 v4 retrieve drag DOM target from drag callback when `this` is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262172/d3-v4-retrieve-drag-dom-target-from-drag-callback-when-this-is-not-available/45262284#45262284)). Thus, this is the correct snippet:

```
selection.attr("class", function (d){
    d3.select(this).attr("class") + " node" + d.id);
});
```

Yet, it is possible to use `classed()` the way you want, not directly (again, you cannot pass a function to it), but in a odd workaround. Just to show you a way to do it using `classed()`, I created a demo code that is **way more hackish** than your solution, for the sake of curiosity. Have a look at it:

```js
var data = [{name: "foo"}, 
            {name: "bar"},
            {name: "baz"}];

var body = d3.select("body");

var divs = body.selectAll("myDivs")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "someClass");

//here comes the hack:
divs.each(function(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("node" + d.name, () => d3.select(this).datum().name == d.name)
});

//log the classes, you can see the previous class ("someClass") was not overwritten:
divs.each(function() {
    console.log(d3.select(this).attr("class"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As `d.name` is provided by the `each()` function, the first argument (`"node" + d.name`) is in fact a string.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found a kind of good solution that is less hacky and may be of interest for anyone that end's up here.
So, instead of trying to do something like:

```css
.cls-type-1 { ... }
.cls-type-2 { ... }
```

```js
selection.classed(d => d.className, true)
```

I ended up switching the classes by atribute selectors, so the js part is straightforward.

```css
*[someAttr="cls-type-1"] { ... }
*[someAttr="cls-type-2"] { ... }
```

```js
selection.attr("someAttr", d => d.className)
```

The only drawbacks I can think of is that you need to hardcode an attribute name and that removing the attribute isn't as easy with d3 as removing a class.