# Retrieve DOM target from drag callback when `this` is not available

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The documentation for [d3.drag](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md#drag_on) states the DOM element target of the drag event will be available in `this` to the callback:

> When a specified event is dispatched, each listener will be invoked with the same context and arguments as selection.on listeners: the current datum d and index i, with the this context as the current DOM element.

But my call back is an object instance and `this` points to that object. So I need another way of accessing the current DOM element that is normally passed in `this`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the second and the third arguments together to get `this` when `this` is not available:

```
d3.drag().on(typename, function(d, i, n) {
  //here, 'this' is simply n[i]
})
```

For a detailed explanation, have a look at the article below that I wrote to deal with `this` in arrow functions. The issue is different from yours, but the explanation is the same.

Here is a basic demo, try to drag a circle and look at the console:

```js
var data = d3.range(5)
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 100);
var circle = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 50 + 50 * d
  })
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("fill", "tan")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", function(d, i, n) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(n[i]))
    }))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I'm using `JSON.stringify` on the D3 selection because Stack snippets freeze if you try to console.log a D3 selection.

---

**Using "this" with an arrow function**

Most of functions in D3.js accept an anonymous function as an argument. The common examples are `.attr`, `.style`, `.text`, `.on` and `.data`, but the list is way bigger than that.

In such cases, the anonymous function is evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed:

1. The current datum (`d`)
2. The current index (`i`)
3. The current group (`nodes`)
4. `this` as the current DOM element.

The datum, the index and the current group are passed as arguments, the famous first, second and third argument in D3.js (whose parameters are traditionally named `d`, `i` and `p` in D3 v3.x). For using `this`, however, one doesn’t need to use any argument:

```
.on("mouseover", function(){
    d3.select(this);
});
```

The above code will select `this` when the mouse is over the element. Check it working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y5fwgopx/

## The arrow function

As a new ES6 syntax, an arrow function has a shorter syntax when compared to function expression. However, for a D3 programmer who uses `this` constantly, there is a pitfall: an arrow function doesn’t create its own `this` context. That means that, in an arrow function, `this` has its original meaning from the enclosing context.

This can be useful in several circumstances, but it is a problem for a coder accustomed to use `this` in D3. For instance, using the same example in the fiddle above, this will not work:

```
.on("mouseover", ()=>{
    d3.select(this);
});
```

If you doubt it, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tfxLsv9u/

Well, that’s not a big problem: one can simply use a regular, old fashioned function expression when needed. But what if you want to write all your code using arrow functions? Is it possible to have a code with arrow functions **and** still properly use `this` in D3?

## The second and third arguments combined

The answer is **yes**, because `this` is the same of `nodes[i]`. The hint is actually present all over the D3 API, when it describes this:

> ...with `this` as the current DOM element (`nodes[i]`)

The explanation is simple: since `nodes` is the current group of elements in the DOM and `i` is the index of each element, `nodes[i]` refer to the current DOM element itself. That is, `this`.

Therefore, one can use:

```
.on("mouseover", (d, i, nodes) => {
    d3.select(nodes[i]);
});
```

And here is the corresponding fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2p2ux38s/

Comment: .on("mouseover", (d, i, nodes) => {
        d3.select(nodes[i]);
    });



This availave in d3 V4 
How can we do this in d3 v3

Comment: @AjinkyaDhote Do this: `.on("mouseover",()=>{d3.select(d3.event.target);})`

Comment: i tried the jsfiddle. it gives the same error i am getting now. may be due to version change or something

Comment: @krishna well, that's not a reason to downvote, since my answer here is clearly correct: you did something else wrong. If you have a problem, I suggest you to post a question reproducing it.