# d3 multiple line charts event.currentTarget doesn't work the same as this when I am using v6

Tags: d3.js, events, this, linechart

Hi I am following this example code and I use it in v6 version:
https://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/e3b8b7c2ca4787f77d78f58d41c3da91
everything works fine but at the end:

```
d3.select(this).select("text").text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));
```

I changed it to

```
 d3.select(event.currentTarget).select("text").text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));
```

the weird thing happened, the event.currentTarget point to the rect, not the g class, so
it doesn't show the text, I tried everything I can do, but have no luck
[image]

it should look like this
[image]

This is such a pain for me, could any one please help me with this, many thanks!

Comment: That `this` is not the same element to which the handler has been attached, which is indeed a rect. Just keep that `this` as it is, that is, don't change that line.

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick response, but I am using v6, select(this) doesn't work, or can you show me a piece of code of what you mean?

Comment: `select(this)` works just fine in v6.

Comment: I got this error: this.querySelector is not a function, does that mean I have problem in other places?

Comment: Yes, you're probably using an arrow function instead of a regular function - that makes that `this` is not the current node, but the `window` element. And the `window` doesn't have a `querySelector` attribute

Comment: I fixed it by changing both the mouseover event function and transform function from arrow function to normal function and problem fixed, doesn't know arrow function has this tricky side effect, thank you so much, you are my lifesaver!

Comment: @XiaoH please read this answer of mine regarding arrow functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262284/5768908

Comment: sure, will do, thank you!