# Add names from array using 'classed'

Tags: d3.js

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddPMVx?editors=1010

It's a simple stacked bar chart

Each stack from the data is in its own layer with a class of 'layer'

I'd like to added another class that is the name of the key from the keys that create the stack

```
.classed('layer', true)

// .classed((i)=>{
//     return keys[i],
// }, true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** use a function with `classed`. For further information, have a look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41970703/5768908).

You can use a getter to get the existing classes and add the one you want. However, pay attention to this: the fact that you use the letter `i` in the argument...

```
function(i){...
```

... doesn't mean that it is the index. The index is the **second** argument, no matter its name. So, it should be:

```
function(_, i){...
```

All that being said, this is a way to add the key name without overriding the existing classes:

```
.attr("class", function(_, i){
    return d3.select(this).attr("class") + " " + keys[i]
});
```

Here is the updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpoKLK?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks again for your help Gerardo. I'm using the graphs in Angular where am using the typescript fat arrow function `(()=>{)`. I was just reading that D3 doesn't really like the fat arrow function, is it best not to use this in D3?

Comment: Well, the problem is that we use `this` a lot in D3... and, using arrow functions, you'll face some problems referencing `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `attr()` function, but make sure it's before your `classed()` call, because it will overwrite all you classes:

```
.attr('class', (_, i) => keys[i])
.classed('layer', true)
```